# Bluetooth not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

After upgrading my Acer Aspire V17 Nitro 791G-792A to windows 10 all bluetooth functionality/support seems to have disappeared. The device manager lacks any bluetooth adapter/device, and when I click view hidden devices the bluetooth appears, though doesn't seem enabled. I've tried downloading and installing all associated bluetooth softwares - such as Bluetooth_Atheros_8.0.1.322_W81x64_A and Bluetooth_Broadcom_12.0.0.9590_W81x64_A, but once installed the stack/bluetooth simply doesn't function.

I've tried searching for the microsoft generic bluetooth software, though to no avail.

I feel as though the hardware itself is present, though interacting with it via bluetooth software is utterly impossible. Any and ALL help is very much appreciated.

UPDATE - [Pics Denoting Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZr4Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to updating to Windows 10 (From 7), my Bluetooth device (Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth) worked correctly without issue. It was typical to leave the adapter in an off state. During upgrade process the (integrated) Bluetooth device was disabled and turned off.

After upgrading to Windows 10, the device was not listed in the "Device Manager" at all. Many different attempts failed including re-enabling the Bluetooth (Windows) services, trying to install old driver (Where Windows 10 refused due to incompatibility), trying Broadcom's Bluetooth SDK to detect the device and failed 100% in finding a way to get bluetooth to work using Windows 10.

**What did work** was loaded a live USB version of Ubuntu (Linux) and simply turned on the device and rebooted back to Window 10. The Bluetooth device was detected immediately, working and found in the Device manager.

For those who want the most straightforward instructions to create a "**LIVE** Linux USB" see -> http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows Then select the option to **Try Ubuntu without install**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. In **Device Manager**, select one of the '**Microsfot Bluetooth LE Enumerator**' entries so it is highlighted, then switch the view to '**Devices by connection**':
[image]

Then select the USB controller that is the *parent*, right-click, & uninstall. Then restart the PC and see if the situation has improved.

Keith